# How to sort on multiple elements of ViewModel - Knockout

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js, typescript

I have a viewmodel that I want to sort by two separate fields (ala a group by in SQL), first by one field alphabetically and then by the second field (also alphabetically). Right now I am only sorting by the second field. I have a sort function in TypeScript that is set up like this:

```
    private sortTable(item): any {
        item.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left.nm == right.nm? 0 : (left.nm < right.nm ? -1 : 1)
        });

        return item;
    }
```

The field that I also want to sort by (the first field) is called fNm in the JavaScript object. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private sortTable(item): any {
    item.sort(function (left, right) {

         if (left.FirstSortField == right.FirstSortField)
            return left.SecondSortField== right.SecondSortField? 0 : (left.SecondSortField< right.SecondSortField? -1 : 1)
         else
            return left.FirstSortField == right.FirstSortField ? 0 : (left.FirstSortField < right.FirstSortField ? -1 : 1)

    return item;
}
```

Note that I did not test this.

Comment: So helpful. You don't need to re-check the FirstSortField in the else block tho. You can also put the statement in a single line using the ? syntax - It's up to the developer to determine what's more readable in their codebase tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think it through, the first name only affects the sort if the last name is equal.

Replace the 0 in your first expression with:

```
(left.fNm == right.fNm ? 0 : (left.fNm < right.fNm ? -1 : 1))
```